# Google Adsense adds not displaying in Internet Explorer and Edge (wordpress site)

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, adsense

Google AdSense adds are not shown when viewing a WordPress website using Internet Explorer and Edge. They are fine when viewing the site in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

This site is running a Cherry theme. The AdSense .js files are being loaded (as seen in the XHR view) and the div container in which the ad should be shown is there (just blank). All AdSense code elements are visible in the elements inspector and no console errors exist.

Comment: So odd that these random down votes pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of fooling around I was able to get this working by adding:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

To the head section of of the theme (in the header.php file).